# Silverstripe $url_handlers not working - runs method but also triggers a 404 error

Tags: php, routes, silverstripe

My controller's $url_handlers are not working. The defined method is called successfully, but a 404 is also triggered.

**EDIT:** Added $allowed_actions for context (thanks [wmk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137738/wmk)).

Example code:

```
class MyPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    . . .

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'test'
    );

    private static $url_handlers = array(
        'view/$ID/test/' => 'test'
    );

    . . .
```

**Note: The static part of the URL `/test`**

Action:

```
class MyPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    . . .

    public function test() {
        var_dump($this->getRequest()->param('ID'), $this->getAction());
        return $this;
    }

    . . .
```

This results in the 404 template being displayed below the var_dump output (using URL `//view/2/test/`):

```
string(1) "2" string(4) "test"
```

Tested in Silverstripe 3.5.1

Comment: is your action "test" in the $allowed_actions array? See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/controllers/access_control/#allowed-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing `/` from the URL pattern.

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'view/$ID/test' => 'test'
);
```

When `HTTPRequest::match()` checks the pattern, it separates it with `explode('/', $pattern)`. The extra `/` causes a discrepancy when `RequestHandler::handleRequest()` later validates that all the parts of the pattern were encountered in the URL (by calling `HTTPRequest::allParsed()`), so it returns a `404`.

Comment: Also, don't `return $this` - controller actions are supposed to return a `SS_HTTPResponse`

Comment: the docs allow trailing slash for routing, i wonder if SilverStripe would really have problems with themfor $url_handlers? The docs' examples are without them... https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/controllers/routing/